# Run a program from Windows run

Tags: windows

There's suppose any application installed in `c:\program files\program.exe`

How do I run this program by simply going to `Start` --> `Run` --> `program.exe`

I tried setting environment variable but that didn't help

I know programs like notepad and cmd run from `Start` --> `Run` cause they are there in the system32 folder. But how do I run an app which is not there?

EDIT:

This is what I did on windows xp:

Right click `My Computer` --> `Properties` --> `advanced -->`environment variables`-->`user variables for administrator`-->`new`-->`"variable name"`&`"variable value"`. In variable value I put the path and in variable name I put an alias for the program
Is what I did correct?

Comment: Comment: Don't install anything in c:\program files, only in its sub-directories.

Answer (score 4):

Windows looks in all directories that are defined in the `%PATH%` variable for programs. You said you tried setting environment variables? How?

It's basically correct. Just add the path `c:\program files\` at the end of the `PATH` variables and you should be fine.

Don't forget to logout / login again if you changed a system wide environment variable.

Comment: this is what i did on windows xp:

right click my computer -- properties -- advanced -- environment variables -- user variables for administrator -- new -- "variable name" & "variable value" ... in variable value i put the path and in variable name i put an alias for the program
is what i did correct?

Comment: No, you should not create a new variable.  Edit the existing variable called PATH to add C:\Program Files\ to the end of it, then log out and back in as socken23 stated.

Comment: The first part is correct. But instead of creating a new variable, look for an existing variable called PATH. Look in the system variables for it. That's the variable name. In the variable value, you should see many folders, seperated by semicolon ;. Just add a semicolon at the end and your additional path. But I do agree with harrymc, it's not the best solution! -too slow ;-)